# WCF check is client callback contract is alive

Tags: wcf

Can you please tell me a way to check if the client is alive on the host?
I am having problems when the client application shuts down or crashes, it does not tell the host that it is disconnecting and the client is still present in the client list on the host.

Then, any other iteraction with the host, hangs and timesout.

Answer (score 1):

Look at [reliable sessions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733136(v=vs.110).aspx) in WCF.  In the simplest case you can just add `<reliableSession>` tag in the binding in configuration file.

Another way is to use [duplex contracts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731064(v=vs.110).aspx).  In this case the service implements an incoming contract; the client implements a callback contract.

Answer (score 0):

i used duplex services but when the client unexpectedly closes down due to a shutdown or crash, the host  is unusable. I need to restart it.

I googled on this issue and i find that when the client unexpectedly closes, the channel is no more usable.

I would like to know how to handle these ususable channels on the host.